# How to use 'top' and 'USER' commands together

Tags: linux

I got a requirement to filter the process results with user context. I am using command like.

```
# top -b -n 1 -p $(pgrep -d',' http)
top - 14:44:13 up 7 days,  3:01,  6 users,  load average: 0.05, 0.01, 0.00
Tasks:   3 total,   0 running,   3 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s):  1.0%us,  1.4%sy,  0.0%ni, 97.4%id,  0.1%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.1%si,  0.0%st
Mem:   8062112k total,  4471344k used,  3590768k free,   176040k buffers
Swap:  6160376k total,       88k used,  6160288k free,   797580k cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND            
27720 root      20   0  175m 3708 1408 S  0.0  0.0   0:05.79 httpd              
27722 daemon    20   0  175m 3076  708 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 httpd              
27723 daemon    20   0 2417m 176m  13m S  0.0  2.2   0:43.19 httpd
```

And I want to get the 'process id' which is under 'root' user context.

Answer (score 1):

`pgrep` supports filtering by process user too:

```
pgrep -u root httpd
```

If you want instead to extract the PID from your `top` output, try this `awk` one-liner:

```
($NF=="httpd" && $2=="root") {print $1}
```

e.g.

```
top -b -n 1 -p $(pgrep -d',' http) | 
  gawk '($NF=="httpd" && $2=="root") {print $1}'
```

Another sometimes useful `pgrep` option is `-o` for oldest matching process, which should be the top-level `httpd` listener process (pgrep is smart enough to try to do the right thing when matching processes have the "same" start time).

Apache is also usually configured to record a pid file, typically somewhere like `/usr/local/apache2/logs/httpd.pid`  or `/var/run/httpd.pid`, that should contain the top-level PID too (though it's slightly less trustworthy as it can be stale).

Answer (score 0):

On Linux, assuming `/proc` is available (if not, you probably have bigger problems getting a complete view of the running processes), you can get the PIDs of all processes belonging to `root` using a command like the following:

```
find /proc -maxdepth 1 -type d -regex '^/proc/[1-9][0-9]*$' -uid 0 -print \
| sed 's,/proc/,,g'
```

Strictly speaking, this will list all directories directly inside /proc which have a name starting with a non-zero digit followed by any number of digits. It then uses `sed` to remove the `/proc/` at the beginning of each line of output, leaving you with simply the numerical PIDs.

The output of this can be further passed to whatever process you like; it'll simply be a list of PIDs, one per line. For example, you could pipe the output to a loop like `while read pid; do something $pid; done` to do `something` to each PID in turn.

On my system the output appears to be sorted numerically but I don't think you can count on that always being the case. `sort` will come in handy otherwise (and depending on what you want to do you may be particularly interested in something like `sort -rn` for a reverse numerical sort).

The `-uid 0` part can be replaced to reference whatever numerical UID you want (or see the `find` man page for other possibilities; for example, `-gid`). If you are interested in your own processes rather than root's, something like `id -u` will come in handy (`-uid $(id -u)`).

Answer (score 0):

The best tool for this would probably be `ps`:

```
   ps displays information about a selection of the active
   processes.  If you want a repetitive update of the selection
   and the displayed information, use top(1) instead.
```

The relevant options here are:

```
   -C cmdlist
          Select by command name.  This selects the processes
          whose executable name is given in cmdlist.
   -o format
          User-defined format.  format is a single argument in
          the form of a blank-separated or comma-separated list,
          which offers a way to specify individual output
          columns.  The recognized keywords are described in the
          STANDARD FORMAT SPECIFIERS section below.
```

So, to find all `httpd` processes that have been launched by root:

```
$ ps -C httpd -o pid,user
  PID USER
27720 root
27722 daemon
27723 daemon
```

Theoretically. passing the `-u root` option to `ps` should return only those processes run by `root` but that doesn't work on my system, not sure why. So we parse:

```
$ ps -C httpd -o pid,user | gawk '$2==root{print $1}'
27720
```

Comment: While that is commonly the case (and it certainly is the case in this particular instance), do note that the awk expression depends on the fact that the desired username does not contain whitespace.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling _can_ a *nix username contain whitespace?

Comment: Good point, you caught me on that one. I'm not sure, but especially in a mixed environment, I don't really see why not.

Comment: I would think that it can't precisely because that would cause problems like what you suggest :). In any case, my debian won't let me create a username that contains a space and I really doubt that any *nix will.

Comment: What the tools let you do is one thing; what you can do hacking /etc/passwd (which would be closer to "can it?") is something very different. `:)`